# Mono For Android: Sending data from clicked listview item to Alert dialog it initializes

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, pass-data

**Click:**

```
lstText.ItemClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    Logon(GetString(Resource.String.LogonMessage), sUUID, sUserId, sUserPIN);
};
```

**Alert Dialog:**

```
private void Logon(string message, string sUUID, string sUserId, string sUserPIN) // 
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            var uuidFetch = this.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService) as Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager;
            var IMEI = uuidFetch.DeviceId;

            var getUserId = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Login, null);
            getUserId.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getUserId).Text = sUserId;

            var getPIN = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Login, null);
            getPIN.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.sUserPin).Text = sUserPIN;

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .SetTitle(GetString(Resource.String.LogonTitle))
            .SetMessage(message)
            .SetView(getUserId)
            .SetView(getPIN)
            .SetCancelable(true)
            .SetPositiveButton(GetString(Resource.String.LogonOk), (sender, e) =>
            {
                sUUID = IMEI;
                sUserId = "474";
                sUserPIN = getPIN.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.sUserPin).Text;
                Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Authorize(sUUID, sUserId, sUserPIN));
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);
            })
            .SetNegativeButton(GetString(Resource.String.LogonCancel), (sender, e) =>
            {
                Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);
            })
            .Show();
        });
```

As you can see in the alert dialog I have my sUserId static (since I'm testing and building the app and I'm really early in developement) but I need it to be a value from the list since every item (ergo user) in the listview has his own sUserId.

**A few lines from my Item Adapter:**

```
var sUserId = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sUserId);
sUserId.Text = item.sUserId != null ? item.sUserId : "";
```

I will provide any further code/info if needed. Thank you for your time, your advice and any hints to help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of the `ItemClick` `Event` you are handling contains a lot of useful stuff, such as the position of the clicked item in the `ListView`s `Adapter`, but also the `View` and its contents.

So if you know the `ListViewItem` view contains a `TextView` you can in your `ItemClick` handler have code like follows, which extracts the content of it:

```
lstText.ItemClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    var userIdTextView = args.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sUserId);
    var userId = userIdTextView.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cheesebaron. Did help me a bit, though I'm still lost on how to actually use userId once the dialog starts?

sorry for newbie questions but I just started out right with dev on C# (haven't really been learning it per say - discovering it as I go, learning by example :) )

Comment: I kind of assumed you knew what to do with the user ID! However after the `var userId...` line you can do whatever you want with it, just like in your first code example, you could call the `Logon` method.

Comment: Ok I had a minor case of stupit yesterday ;D
sUserId = fetchUserId;
before the logon method... no need for the textfield as well :)

Thank you for all the help!